# handle camera flip while recording video without stop it react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to recording video using RNcamera in react native and i want to change or flip camera to rear/front while recording video.
It flip but stop the recording of video automatically without any interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `RNCamera` doesn't support this functionality yet. Here's a [feature request](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/726) for this feature. You can keep an eye on it for any updates, although it doesn't look good so far.